# ie7 float div left padding issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix [this site's](http://www.community.hallgreenchristadelphians.co.uk/) ie7 issue with the bottom columns. The 3 columns should total 960px and take the whole width of the container, but for some reason there is an issue with the padding. I have checked the lastest firefox/chrome and it works great.
If anybody could help me with this that would be great
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this doctype:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Comment: I would recommend not using this doctype and using the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: You're also missing a closing HTML tag on the page I think.

Comment: @HAWKES08 You can payout by voting up the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure but try displaying inline the floated elements.

```
.selector{
    display:inline;
}
```